# Event listener stops to execute

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

After  initialization of the player and video playback it is necessary to move the pleer on dom tree. After that iframe is updated and event listener onReady is executed and event listener onStateChange ceases to hold.
I have tried to delete and add event listener onStateChange, but the method player.removeEventListener('onStateChange', 'onPlayerStateChange') doesn’t work even before moving the player. Example of this problem:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        var player, pauseCounter = 0;

        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        function onPlayerReady( event ) {
            console.log('PlayerReady');

            player.playVideo();
            setTimeout( function(){ player.pauseVideo(); pauseCounter++; }, 3000 );
        }

        function onPlayerStateChange( event ) {
            console.log( 'StateChange ' + event.data );

            if ( +event.data == 2 && pauseCounter == 1 ) {
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(document.getElementById('player'));
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

How can I keep track of onstateChange event again after the update iframe.
Thanks.

Added playground: https://jsbin.com/xuhuyugemi/edit?js,console,output